# How do I show the eigenvalues of a positive definite matrix are real and positive?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given A is a positive definite matrix, how would I show the eigenvalues of A are real and positive? I know  is positive (and hence real) for any x, so how could I apply it to an orthogonal set of eigenvectors?

Comment: You left out a mathematical expression near the start of the second sentence, probably $\langle Ax,x\rangle$.

Comment: Woops! Yes it was. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Ax=\lambda x$. Now, $<Ax,x>=<\lambda x,x> = \lambda <x,x>$. Now, $<Ax,x>=<x,A^{*}x>=<x,Ax>=\overline{\lambda}<x,x>$. As $x$ is non zero, we get that $\lambda = \overline{\lambda}$, that is, $\lambda$ is real.

Now, since $A$ is positive, we know that $<Ax,x> \geq 0$ for all $x$. (in fact equal to $0$ only if $x=0$.) Applying this to all eigen vectors we see that the eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: Thank you! It seems so simple.. Apparently I'm rusty on my skills.

Comment: Don't worry. :)

Comment: Any suggestions for using the complex version of the spectral theorem to prove its corollary?

Comment: See the book- Operator Alegebras by Kehe Zhu. He does it there, and the book's great. Of course you might use other books too; this is a standard result. Hope that helps.

Comment: Anywhere I can find it without having to buy the book?

Comment: Probably a Library. I didn't get it online.

Comment: Ok thanks you!!